# Angular mat-table function isAllSelected() running infinitely

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using an Angular material mat-table for showing table data, but I noticed that this function is executing infinitely after we initialize datasource of the table.

html code:

```
         <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="padding: 0px;">
                            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? toggleAllRows() : null"
                                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="false"
                                [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" (change)="$event ? selectRow($event, row) : null"
                                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

.ts code:

```
  isAllSelected() {


const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;

this.rowsToSend = this.selection.selected;

console.log('is all selected execution started');

return numSelected === numRows; 

 }
```

Once data is loaded it starts infinitely.

I want to know if it is the default behavior of this, if yes it leads to memory leakage.
If not, how to deal with this?

Comment: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular method calls in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866591/angular-method-calls-in-template)